# Handling collection changed events of MvxObservableCollection in standard RecyclerView

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an MvxObservableCollection

```
public MvxObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
        {
            get => items;
            set => SetProperty(ref items, value);
        }
```

Collection was initialized and after I inserted and removed some items to it.
I use standard `RecyclerView` and native `RecyclerView.Adapter` instead of `MvxRecyclerView` and `MvxRecyclerAdapter`

How to handle collection changed events in Fragment in this case?

`ViewModel.Items.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;` doesn't work

Comment: Hi, if using `MvxObservableCollection` from **Mvvmcross**, why not using `MvxRecyclerView` and  `MvxRecyclerAdapter`? Navtive android not contains the usage of `MvxObservableCollection`. If [the document of Mvvmcross](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/android/android-recyclerview?scroll=300) contains the usage for native `RecyclerView`, that should be possible, otherwise it is impossible.

Comment: I agree with @JuniorJiang-MSFT because you lose all the power that Mvx brings you and you could also just inherit from `MvxRecyclerView` or `MvxRecyclerAdapter` and adapt them to your logic but if you still need to do that guide yourself with the MvvmCross Code [MvxRecyclerView](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/6.4.2/MvvmCross.Android.Support/V7.RecyclerView/MvxRecyclerView.cs)  and  [MvxRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/6.4.2/MvvmCross.Android.Support/V7.RecyclerView/MvxRecyclerAdapter.cs)